# How to delete an element in a custom array? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a custom inspector for a custom Package class based on PropertyDrawer, but since I need an array of these Packages, I need to create a custom array for them. So, as you can see in the attached screenshot below, I created something like an array. Everything works perfectly except for deleting an item. I need to select an element and pass this selected element to the code so that I can determine the Package index that I need to delete.

[image]

Comment: by the sounds of it you need a list not an array

Comment: @BugFinder the drawer in Unity is actually the same for both `List<T>` and `T[]` ... @OP .. why exactly do you need a custom array implementation? What is wrong with the default one (= Reorderable list)?

Comment: https://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist ... Nowadays this is actually the default drawer for lists and arrays .. so only having a custom property drawer for the list elements should actually be enough already ..